# Searching for an integral

Tags: analysis

I am looking for a continous function $F:[-1,2]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $F'(x)$ is for $x\in (-1,0)\cup(0,1)\cup (1,2)$ equal to the function $$f:[-1,2]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f(x)=\begin{cases}4x-1&-1\le x<0\\2x+3&0\le x<1\\1-x&1\le x\le 2\end{cases}.$$

Is it possible to chose $F$ such that $F'(0)$ and $F'(1)$ exists?

If I set $$F(x)=\begin{cases}2x^2-x&-1\le x<0\\x^2+3x&0\le x<1\\x-(x^2-7)/2&1\le x\le 2\end{cases}$$

this would do the job. But what about the second question?

Comment: I think you need the Fourier series of $f$.

Comment: I don't know anything about Fourier series :(

Comment: @MyGlasses: the Fourier series have nothing to do here ?!

Comment: It suffices to adjust the integration constants to achieve continuity between the three pieces.

Comment: Yes this is what I did. But the question if $F$ can be chosen such that $F'(0)$ and $F'(1)$ exist is what I don't know :)